# Does it make sense to write an offline mobile web app in html5?

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile

I am investigating options for a web app aimed at mobiles and one of the options is to write a standalone app that does not connect to the internet at all. Does it make sense to consider using HTML5 for this? The main reason for considering HTML5 as far as I'm concerned is the fact that it works cross-platform, but I just don't know if it makes any sense to consider this option if it will only be used offline once it has been initially downloaded.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, this is definitely possible. I think the other answers don't quite give enough information, or understand the question, so let me provide a bit more.

Yes, it is possible to create a mobile app in HTML, either from scratch by using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) as the platform, or by using a mobile framework such as [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

PhoneGap allows you to create true mobile apps using HTML5, CSS & JavaScript, and utilising the PhoneGap API to utilise features found in smartphones such as a camera, motion sensor, gps, storage etc.

Using jQuery Mobile, you'll be creating a mobile website, which must be accessed using the phone's browser, however you are able to incorporate this framework into the PhoneGap platform. This allows you to create a more native feeling app in HTML5.

I think the question you should be asking is what language should I use?. It doesn't matter if the app is used online or offline. What matters is what language or platform you want to write it in. There are downsides to using HTML5 to write mobile apps (speed, scalability, quality, approval to name a few).

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem for doing so. HTML5 gives you ways to store information locally and a big set of other functionnalities. This could help you find if there is what you want regarding the mobile browsers (and Androïd's): http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Then you may look into MVC frameworks like dojo toolkit (if you want widgets out of the box), backbone.js and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. in fact many cross platform app out there is using HTML5 or javascript.

you could take a look on [phonegap.com](http://phonegap.com/). It's cross platform using html5

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to create an application with HTML5 (and javascript if needed).
Coding your app in HTML5 makes it easier to port to other mobile OS.
Just keep in mind that HTML5 is not definite yet, so you MAY have to rewrite certain parts after some time.

Phonegap can be used for this, as some already suggested.
If you're comfortable with java, but just want a HTML5 app so you can port it later,
you can use Google GWT (which converts java into HTML5 and javascript)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but I don't think it's the best choice for an app that won't connect to the web at all.  HTML5 offline apps are designed to work for the short periods of time where there is no web connection, not really for apps that will never connect to the web.  Plus, HTML5 local storage is limited.  I'm not sure what the limitations are off of the top of my head, but I think you'd be better off taking another route.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely! There are already developers looking into it. HTML5 has native like capabilities, such as writing to its own DB and etc. Like they said, HTML5 is not definitive yet, so it might take awhile for it to be feasible and adopted by all.

Imagine 1 language to rule them all :)